# Moodle-Bigcommerce Integration

Tags: moodle

Actually , i have moodle website. I want to integrate with big commerce website.
If user log into my moodle website, they automatically login in big commerce website.
Any plugin, extension or app available for it.

Comment: Not sure if this is the right place to post as not a programming question per se. Have you tried googling this topic already?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like BigCommerce uses OAuth2

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/authentication

So you will need an oauth2 plugin for Moodle

https://moodle.org/plugins/browse.php?list=set&id=40